# how to vertically align panels withing Java AWT/Swing

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jpanel

I'm wondering how exactly to use swing. I'd like to align 3 panels so that panel 1 is on top of panel 2, which is then on top of panel 3. Each of these panels will then have their own labels/buttons within it.

Each of these then needs to contain their own labels/buttons inside the panels.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a `GridBagLayout` or `GridLayout`.  Start by having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

## `GridBagLayout`

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

add(new ExamplePane(1), gbc);
add(new ExamplePane(2), gbc);
add(new ExamplePane(3), gbc);
```

## `GridLayout`

[image: GridLayout]

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

add(new ExamplePane(1));
add(new ExamplePane(2));
add(new ExamplePane(3));
```

## Important

There are significant differences between the two and you will need to read the linked tutorial and supporting documentation on both these layouts to understand how they work and which might be best suited to you're immediate needs